# Newbie trying to insert data into SQL Server 2008 from excel

Tags: sql, vb.net, excel, sql-server-2008, insert

I have been trying the last few days and what I have been doing is googling and trying whatever code I can find and testing out. I give up and hoping the brilliant minds here can help me.

I am trying to load data from an excel worksheet to an already existing table in SQL Server. All the columns and data attributes matches exactly.

When I run the script it gives an error:

> Run-time error '-2147217865 (80040e37)':
>   The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'DATA_FOR_CUTTING'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path correctly. If the 'DATA_FOR_CUTTING' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator

This is the script (I am using Excel 2010)

```
Sub Excel_To_SQL()
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim con2 As New ADODB.Connection
Dim s As String
Dim s2 As String
Dim s3 As String
Dim WSP1 As Worksheet
Set con = New ADODB.Connection

Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.StatusBar = "Contacting SQL Server..."

s = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\Users\xxx\Documents\xxx\xxxx\Book2.xlsx';" _
         & "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=0;Readonly=False"";"
'                    'HDR = yes - to exclude header of excel file upon reading
con.Open s

s2 = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Data Source=xxxxx;"
con2.Open s2

s3 = "INSERT INTO dbo.DATA_FOR_CUTTING SELECT * FROM [Data_for_Cutting$]"
con.Execute s3

con.Close
Set con = Nothing

Application.StatusBar = "Data successfully loaded."
End Sub
```

#

I fixed the connection string and there are no more errors, but it also does nothing. Its not reading the contents of the worksheet so no rows are being inserted to the sql table. But if I do the "INSERT INTO ... VALUES (XXX)" command the VALUES are inserted into the SQL table, so the connection and command are working. Anybody know why its not reading the worksheet? Thanks.

Comment: is your table exist ? check for your table name given or the sheet name you have provided

Comment: Does your spreadsheet have a sheet called Data_for_Cutting?

Comment: I've just come across this http://epplus.codeplex.com/ it looks like this can help... plenty of examples.   Also your error mentions Access DB while your narative says Excel to SQL 2008 are you using the wrong provider in s.

Comment: hi, yes the table exisits in sql and there is a sheet called Data_for_Cutting in the excel file. I'll check the epplus site. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about using Excel's ability to compose strings in order to generate SQL?  For example, let's say I have these cells:

```
A       B
Name    Phone
Andrei  555-555-4444
Alex    555-555-3333
```

Then in cell C2, I could enter

`="insert into mytable(name, phone) values('"&A2&"','"&B2"');"`

And to deal with 10,000 such rows, of course simply copy the formula.

On the other hand, to do this programmatically, you already have some code to connect to SQL Server, so all you need is something to convert a range in Excel to SQL.  Let's say for instance we assume that our range will always have the SQL field names as the first row, as shown above, then this macro may just do the trick:

```vb
' Convert a named range to SQL insert statements. First row must have SQL field names.
Public Function RangeToSQL( _
            strExcelRangeName As String, _
            strSQLTableName As String, _
            Optional strSheetName As String = "Sheet1" _
            ) As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName)
    Set rng = sh.Range(strExcelRangeName)

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, vt As Variant, strFields As String, strValues As String
    For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
        strFields = strFields + IIf(j = 1, "", ",")
        strFields = strFields + rng.Cells(1, j).Value
    Next j
    For i = 2 To rng.Rows.Count
        strValues = strValues + IIf(i = 2, "", "," + vbCrLf)
        For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
            strValues = strValues + IIf(j = 1, "(", ",")
            vt = rng.Cells(i, j).Value
            strValues = strValues + IIf(IsNumeric(vt), CStr(vt), "'" + CStr(vt) + "'")
        Next j
        strValues = strValues + ")"
    Next i
    RangeToSQL = "insert into " + strSQLTableName + "(" + strFields + ") values " + strValues + ";"
End Function
```

For the cells shown above defined into a named range, this generates the following SQL:

```sql
insert into whatevertable(Name,Phone) values ('Andrei','555-555-4444'),
('Alex','555-555-3333');
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. the tab has thousands of rows and it changes everyday. and the user dont have access to sql so i have to execute the sql command from excel.

Comment: You could write a macro that would essentially do the same thing as what I described as formulas above.  So you would iterate through the rows, building a set of insert statements, and just send one big batch of SQL over your connection when you're done iterating.  Do you want a little sample code for that?

Comment: I would love to see a sample for that :). Thanks!

Comment: Updated post (for sample).

Answer (score 0):

Personally when I'm doing this kind of thing I copy out the existing column headers into a separate sheet from SQL Server.

Then I copy each column of data underneath the corrisponding headers.

Then from the "Edit top 200 rows" option after right clicking the table, I paste in the data from excel.

Comment: for a one time thing i think i agree with you. but the excel tab is updated by multiple macros and almost everyday so i have to provide an automated way to load the data to sql. the excel was not mine. thanks.

Comment: Yeah on a one off basis it's great. Not fit for what you're after though

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the SQL version I am using was an older version and it does not work with 2007 (or newer), so I have to use 2003 version.